# Testing Symfony2 Console Commands that expect input

Tags: php, symfony, console, console-application

I am trying to test my Symfony2 Console command using phpunit.

I'm following the Symfony2 cookbook article about this topic:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/helpers/questionhelper.html#testing-a-command-that-expects-input

However, if I fail to provide an input (a test fail), then phpunit simply sit there doing nothing waiting for input. Here's an example:

```
// MyCommand.php
class MyCommand extends Command {
  // ... configure()

  protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output) {
     $qh = $this->getHelper('question');
     $q1 = new ConfirmationQuestion('First question, yes or no?', false);
     $qh->ask($input, $output, $q);
     $q2 = new ConfirmationQuestion('Second question, yes or no?', false);
     $qh->ask($input, $output, $q);
  }
}

// MyCommandTest.php
class MyCommandTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
  // ... getInputstream()

  public function testExecute() {
    $app = new Application();
    $app->add(new MyCommand());

    $cmd = $app->find('askquestions');
    $cmdTester = new CommandTester($cmd);

    $helper = $cmd->getHelper('question');
    $helper->setInputStream($this->getInputStream('y\\n')); // this should be yy\\n

    $cmdTester->execute([
       'command' => $cmd->getName(),
    ]);
  }
}
```

Please notice that I have purposefully made my test incorrect, it is only supplying an answer to question 1. Since I wrote that test, I have since added q2 but I forgot to modify my tests. Being a good programmer though I run phpunit to see if there are problems, but phpunit hangs as it expects input from q2!

How do I make it so my test will disregard any further requests for input, fail if it encounters one, and keep going with other tests?

Comment: One possible solution is to go against the Symfony2 Cookbook article recommendation of using setInputStream and instead mock'ing the question helper so it does not actually ask for input. (http://marekkalnik.tumblr.com/post/32601882836/symfony2-testing-interactive-console-command)  This works, but I was wondering what the Symfony way was.

Comment: Did you find a way to make it work with the setInputStream ? i m facing the same issue

Comment: It won't work properly and is rather clunky. You have to mock the QuestionHelper as my answer bellow states, I wrote a library to do this easily and cleanly.

Comment: i finally make it work by choosing a ChoiceQuestion instead of QuestionHelper.